# How to get rid of new mattress smell?

Tags: furniture

I have a new foam mattress and it smells. Apparently it needs to be aired out for several days. Is there anything I can do to speed up this process? I'm thinking temperature, humidity, fans, baking soda?

Comment: I suggest airing it with fresh air and fans in a different room than where you'll be sleeping.  Then, if you're quite sensitive to the off-gassing, you could put it in a large plastic bag during the night for the first few days.

Answer (score 5):

Coming from a place on earth where we can't leave stuff outside all the day due to the weather conditions, I would leave the mattress standing on the long side edge in a ventilated room.

This would maximize the surface area exposed to the air, which would help vent away the new mattress smell slightly faster.

Comment: The smell did not clear after 2 weeks. I complained to the retailer. They replaced it. I aired out the replacement like you said, on one side. That one worked after a few days :)

Answer (score 1):

All you must do is follow these simple steps:

1. Open the mattress
2. Put the mattress on its side
3. Open all the windows and doors which are in the room of the mattress
4. Try to create a cross-breeze (this is by opening the doors of multiple rooms and allowing the air to enter through one window in one room, and leave from another window in another room
5. After 24 hours your mattress should smell of nothingness!

Answer (score 1):

I was frequently dealing with smelly cloths, after going to a pub( where there was always a lot of smoke) then friend told me to put the things overnight on a radiator(heater with circulating hot water). It helped a lot.

The hot air makes the circulation, the heat will help the smelly particles dissipate.

I would suggwst putting it into the sun somewhere for a day or more. It should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, using baking soda will help, but I´ll suggest to use it with *essential oil* in addition.

So, if you still have the (plastic) bag the mattress was packaged in, put it back in the bag and insert a small box with baking soda, and add a few drops of essential oil (lavender or another aroma you like). If possible, put tape on the bag (to disallow air flow) and leave it like this about 6-8 hours.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is incorrect. The odor of a new foam mattress is from the synthetic polyurethane resins that build up in small quantities in the air-tight packaging the mattress is shipped in. This is very similar to the material used in paint and adhesives, but you wouldn't recommend closing up a newly painted surface with baking soda and an Airwick to get rid of the smell. You need to let those compounds off gas — not close them in with essential oils — in order to get rid of them safely.

Comment: I know what I am talking about cause I do this two times with new pillows.The idea is to mask smell for few days, exactly enough to smell retire from mattress naturally. Keeping mattress with essential oil in bag didn´t get smell worse.
And you can´t compare painted room and foam mattress (and using baking soda to get rid of smell in room :) ), even materials are similar.

Comment: Masking the smell might be ok in some cases, but in my case the gases affect my sinus, and essential oils would likely make this worse.

Answer (score 0):

My mother always kept newly bought mattresses in the sun from morning to evening in an aerated region, and then repeated this for a week.

This probably reduce the smell of the matress.

Answer (score 0):

Simples. Spray this on the mattress:

[https://www.amazon.com/Chemical-Guys-AIR-101-16-Freshener-Eliminator/dp/B002J7VX4Y/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1492309817&sr=8-1&keywords=new+car+smell](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002J7VX4Y)

Now it will smell like new car smell, not new mattress smell.

Comment: I'm not sure that was quite the effect desired. :)